# python: copy specific lines from one file to anther file

Tags: python

I have a file, that i want to copy only specific lines from it to anther file. I tried to create a function:

```
def copytotemp(logfile, fromline, toline):
    with open(logfile) as origfile:
        with open("templog.log", "w") as tempfile:
            for num, line in enumerate(origfile, 0):
                if (num + 1) <= fromline and (num + 1) >= toline:
                    tempfile.write(line)
```

but tempfile.log is always empty.
thanks

Comment: `if (num + 1) <= fromline and (num + 1) >= toline:` ? Are you sure ? Looks like you got the comparison operators backward...

Comment: Oh and yes BTW :  `enumerate()` takes an optional `start` argument (defaulting to `0`) so if you want 1-based line numbers you can use `enumerate(origfile, 1)` and get rid of the `num+1` stuff.

Comment: thanks, that was the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a mistake with the operators.

```
def copytotemp(logfile, fromline, toline):
    with open(logfile) as origfile:
        with open("templog.log", "w") as tempfile:
            for num, line in enumerate(origfile, 1):
                if num >= fromline and num <= toline:
                    tempfile.write(line)
```

is working

Comment: You may also want to have a look at `itertools.islice()`